# Extracting array of numbers from an array of dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have the following 2x2 array of dictionaries:

```
a = np.array([[{'x_id':0, 'y_id':0},{'x_id':1, 'y_id':1}],[{'x_id':2, 'y_id':0},{'x_id':3, 'y_id':1}]])
```

I would like to get a 2x2 array of numbers corresponding to the values of the key `'x_id'`, `[[0, 1], [2, 3]]`, i.e.:

```
0  1
2  3
```

Is there a way other than a double for loop? That is:

```
numbers = [[a[i,j]['x_id'] for j in range(2)] for i in range(2)]
```

Comment: A list of (lists of) dictionares  would be just as good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about *explicit* for loop within the code, you can `flatten` your array and get the job done using a single for loop, followed by a reshape of your final array

```
numbers = np.array([i['x_id'] for i in a.flatten()]).reshape(a.shape)
# array([[0, 1],
#        [2, 3]])
```

An alternate solution would be using `itemgetter` on a flattened array as

```
import operator
numbers = np.array(list(map(operator.itemgetter('x_id'), a.flatten()))).reshape(a.shape)
```

**Performance**: Both the methods take similar times

```
%timeit np.array([i['x_id'] for i in a.flatten()]).reshape(a.shape)
# 4.16 µs ± 676 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit np.array(list(map(operator.itemgetter('x_id'), a.flatten()))).reshape(a.shape)
# 4.9 µs ± 1.26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```